# jQuery .load(); not working with image

Tags: jquery, html, download, animated-gif

I am trying to create a browser plug-in which keeps `.gif`s faded out until they are fully loaded. Once the images are loaded, they fade in.

HTML

```
<img src="http://media.tumblr.com/6ced3000389da1433b13c8a18bfeaf75/tumblr_inline_muf6jmZS8m1rc3mra.gif" alt="">

<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-fYJrkNWec08/T9EYOmNGPNI/AAAAAAAAC04/UtdRRM8a3hc/s640/cat-fat-dancing-cat-gif.gif" alt="">
```

jQuery

```
$("img[src$='gif']").each( function() {
    $(this).css({'opacity': '0.05'});
    $(this).load( function() {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMJ72/)

However, the images don't fade in as the `.load` function is never activated.

What am I doing wrong? The jQuery docs do mention some cross browser issues, but this was tested in the latest version of both Chrome and Safari and both failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a little plain javascript is usually easier when checking for `image.onload` :

```
$("img[src$='gif']").each( function() {
    var self = $(this).css({'opacity': '0.05'});

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        self.fadeTo('fast', 1)
    }
    img.src = this.src;

    if (img.complete) img.onload();
});
```

And note that `fadeIn()` only works with hidden images, not images that are visible with a lower opacity, which is the real issue with your code.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WMJ72/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The `load` function is activated and you can do whatever you want after

```
$("img[src$='gif']").each( function() {
        $(this).css({'opacity': '0.05'});
        $(this).one('load', function() {
      alert('Image Loaded'); 
    }).each(function() {
      if(this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
    });
```